Generating netcat HTTP response after request not before
This works
while true; do /root/bin/report.sh | nc -l -p 8888 -q 1; sleep 1; done

except that report.sh is executed and then it waits for a connection, so the report is out of date by the time it gets sent out.
I tried this
nc -l -p 8888 -c "/root/bin/report.sh nc"

which does send the output to the browser, and it flashes up briefly in the browser but then the browser shows an error page saying The connection was reset. Tried -q -1 and -k but they don't do anything.
The nc parameter to the script it to let me add HTTP headers
if [ "$1" = "nc" ]; then
        # HTTP status line.
        echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Connection: close Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
fi

but they don't do anything.
Strangely, wget thinks there are no headers. It also complains about connection being closed.
# wget localhost:8888
--2024-11-12 20:56:34--  http://localhost:8888/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8888... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 No headers, assuming HTTP/0.9
Length: unspecified
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                        [                     <=>                          ]   1.26K   201 B/s    in 5.9s

2024-11-12 20:56:40 (221 B/s) - Read error at byte 1293 (Connection reset by peer).Retrying.

What's going on?
Update: curl -vv
# curl -vv localhost:8888
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8888...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8888 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8888
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
* Closing connection 0
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
C ~/bin# Error: writing output failed: Broken pipe
/root/bin/report.sh: 20: echo: echo: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 27: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 27: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 27: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 27: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 27: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 27: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 30: echo: echo: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 31: echo: echo: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 32: echo: echo: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 34: echo: echo: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 35: echo: echo: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 36: echo: echo: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 42: echo: echo: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 44: echo: echo: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 50: echo: echo: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 61: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 61: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 61: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 61: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 68: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 68: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 68: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 68: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 68: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 70: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 71: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 76: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 76: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 76: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 76: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 76: printf: printf: I/O error
/root/bin/report.sh: 76: printf: printf: I/O error
sort: fflush failed: 'standard output': Broken pipe
sort: write error

Update: different headers that also don't work
if [ "$1" = "nc" ]; then
        while read -r line; do
                echo "read $line"
        done
        # HTTP status line.
        echo -e -n "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        echo -e -n "Connection: close\r\n"
        echo -e -n  "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
        echo -e -n  "\r\n"
fi


nc (generically -- there are lots of different, completely independently written tools shipped under the same name, so it's hard to tell which features any given implementation will have) is the wrong tool for the job. Use socat, or tcpsvd, or really any inetd/xinetd implementation that can run an arbitrary subprocess with stdin/stdout wired to a socket.

...right now, there's even a race condition where if too connections come in too close to each other one will be dropped. You really want a tool that forks a subprocess per connection to avoid that; nc is just flatly unfit for the use.

BTW, in the nc -c case (for a competent implementation), you can read from stdin and only write any output after you've received a full set of request headers; that exact same trick will also work with the tools I recommended above; that way you can make sure what you're receiving is really a GET request, or route different URLs to different report parameters, or so forth.

Debian 12. It's definitely nothing to do with simultaneous connections because there's only me using it.

So where would you put the read in that command?

Note that the first thing works except that it makes the output then waits for a request. All I need is to do it the other way round -- make the output after receiving the request.

The read goes inside the script when running in nc mode.

Might look something like: if [ "$1" = nc ]; then read -r request; [[ $request = "GET "* ]] || { echo "Ignoring invalid request: $request" >&2; exit 1; }; while read -r line && [[ ${line%$'\r'} ]]; do :; done; fi -- again, this only works when you're using nc in a mode where it wires up stdin (if your version of nc even supports that -- not all do -- or, better, using one of the non-nc tools I recommended), it won't work at all when you're piping, because that's purely unidirectional.

If you want us to be able to describe what's going on in any detail, you're going to put your HTTP client in verbose mode. curl -vv should have enough information; wget or curl or its own won't.

(btw, note that the script fragment I gave above has some bash-only syntax -- be sure you start it with an appropriate shebang so it's run with bash, not sh, as the interpreter. BTW, using .sh file extensions on bash scripts, which are not sh scripts, is frowned on; better to just have no extensions on your executables at all -- you don't run ls.elf or pip.py, after all).

And there are no valid response headers: you're not adding newlines in your example. printf '%s\r\n' 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' 'Connection: close' 'Content-Type: text/plain' '' would be a less-wrong alternative; notice that we're putting a \r\n after every line of response header, plus an extra blank line at the end before starting the output content.

Accroding to RFC2616 the HTTP response has a single status line that contains the headers delimited by something called SP which I think is space. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6

Yes, there's one status line. No, the full set of headers are not included on that line -- they follow it as separate lines, one each, up until the next blank line. Sniff literally any other HTTP client connection.

If you read the spec you linked correctly, you see it says *((general-header | request-header | entity-header) CRLF) CRLF message-body. Because the * (meaning zero-or-more-repetitions) refers to the entire block including the CRLF, that CRLF is repeated after each and every header line, and then you have a second CRLF (creating a blank line) at the end of the block of headers before the body.

Your echo "read $line" needs to be redirected to stderr for you-the-user to see it logged, and you need to stop the loop and start writing output as soon as you see a blank line on input. Use the exact code I gave you, don't build your own buggy version and act like it's my fault when it doesn't work.

Yeah, I can't get the while to exit in plain sh, not bash.

(also, in determining what "as soon as you see a blank line on input" means, you need to consider a line containing only a carriage return literal blank; that's what the [[ ${line%$'\r'} ]] does. I'm not giving you complicated code for funsies -- I'm giving you complicated code because each thing that looks weird fixes a very specific bug)

In sh, I'd probably do something like cr=$(printf '\r') once at the top of your program, and then later in the read loop use test "$line" = "$cr" || test -z "$line" to see if that line is empty. But I also wouldn't use sh if I could possibly help it.

(and if you're using sh, you really shouldn't be using echo -en -- the POSIX sh standard makes echo -n output undefined, and echo -e completely illegal if it does anything except print -e on output; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly including the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections).

Reading the request is a red herring; I don't need to do that. How can I get wget/curl to see the headers?

Already went over that -- gave you a printf command that writes them properly with a CRLF after each line of header, and two CRLFs after all the headers are complete. You still ought to read the request, though -- someone could write a HTTP client that didn't read input until after it was able to successfully flush the associated request, and your code would be buggy with that client if it didn't consume headers.

echo "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" makes curl happy, but then everything after that it thinks is the body

It only thinks that because your line above is writing two \ns not one (because you didn't use -n to suppress the default... but again, see the linked POSIX spec for echo advising users to use printf instead when they need that feature)

Where are the two \n in echo "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" ?

You're writing one \n explicitly, and the second is the one echo always writes by default at the end of each line when not called with the -n argument.

(If you'd followed my advice and used the printf I gave to write the whole response header block at once we wouldn't be having this conversation. Why are we having this conversation?)

So the reason you want to use printf instead of echo because echo adds a trailing newline and echo's -n flag doesn't work in plain sh.

"isn't guaranteed to work" more than "won't work"; depends on exactly which sh you have, but if you want a more comprehensive writeup and the standard document I linked is too dry, see Why is printf better than echo? over on [unix.se].

So changing from echo to printf has got the browser seeing the response headers. Can't get the while to exit, and the browser still says the connection was reset -- which was the original problem. curl says * Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

(echo -n is undefined behavior, as is echo 'hi\r\n' with backslashes -- they might do what you want or might not, depending on whether the sh implementation you're using follows BSD or AT&T traditions -- because of politics, the committee writing the spec made both approaches legal; this is all spelled out explicitly in the specification I linked earlier).

I would expect that error from wget if it didn't receive/parse/recognize the Connection: close header. Does curl -vv now show it recognizing that header correctly?

BTW, keepalive (the feature Connection: close turns off) is a HTTP/1.1 thing; if you only claimed to support HTTP/1.0, then it would be implicitly off by default.

Mind, it's also possible that you're getting errors from the client because the outbound side of the connection was ended before it was able to write all its request headers. Writing a response before you have the full request remains generally iffy behavior in general for a server that isn't sophisticated enough to do it well (HTTP pipelining is a thing that exists, but... well, there are specifications around how to do it right).
